# Can I use getopt in C++ to read a character both as with and without argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, command-line-arguments, getopt

I have to print two different outputs if the user chooses `-p` as opposed to `-pc`. One with the argument and other without the argument. If I try:

```
while( (arg = getopt_long(argc, argv, "p:")) != -1 )
{
    switch (arg)
    {
    case 'p':
        p = optarg;
        if (p=='')
            sflag = true;
        if (p=='c')
            oflag = true;        
        break;
}
```

Then `-pc` works, but if I try `-p`, I get an error saying expecting an argument. How can I handle an optional option argument?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using GNU? If so, you're in luck. From the [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt):

> The *options* argument is a string that specifies the option characters that are valid for this program. An option character in this string can be followed by a colon (`:`) to indicate that it takes a required argument. **If an option character is followed by two colons (`::`), its argument is optional; this is a GNU extension.**

Thus, you'd want:

```
while( (arg = getopt_long(argc, argv, "p::")) != -1 )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Yes I am using GNU.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my code here and I am using two colons in the code

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
char op= '\0';
char arg = '\0';
while( (arg = getopt(argc, argv, "p::")) != -1 ){
switch (arg){
case 'p': op = *optarg;
if (op=='c')
flagp = true;
else if (op=='')
flago = true;
else
cout<<"Invalid parameter"<<endl;
}}

I am getting a empty character constant as an error and if I leave it blank as shown above
```

`and other approach as shown below if i do not use else.'

```
case 'p': op = *optarg;
          flagp = true;
}
It does not take -p as an argument. Compiler gives me a segmentation dump error. But if i use any argument like px then it sets the flagp as true.
```

Comment: I used this     {else if (op=='\0')} in the above code  for resolving empty constant error but still segmentation fault (core dumped) is coming.